# Problem while setting data from API using useState - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my res.data.enquiry - object I'm getting from api call

```
{
        active: true
         createdAt: "2021-09-03T05:58:32.584Z"
        ID: {category: Array(1),
          Images: Array(5),
          _id:'6131b96650a4b8127f7c59c8', 
           loginMethod: 0,
           phone: '65565656', …}
          messages: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
             __v: 3
            _id: "COOK000000000036"
}
```

My UseState where I initialized the SingleEnq as an empty object to set it with res.data.enquiry during the fetch from api. (also tried null)

```
const [singleEnq, setSingleEnq] = useState({});
```

My fetch function

```
 function getOneticket(userID) {
        axios
          .get(`admin/enquiry/get/one?enquiryID=${userID}`)
          .then((res) => {
            setSingleEnq(res.data.enquiry)
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err, "error message for get one ");
          });
      }
```

My useState remains empty. Dont know the reason. It's not setting up the data from the api.

Comment: How you know singleEnq `remains empty.`?

Comment: how do you call `getOneticket`?

Comment: I consoled it in useEffect @Viet

Comment: In a button click. The function is running. I checked with a console text. @TungPham

Comment: Please show detail component, Your code you provide works well

Comment: Sorry, are you asking for the useEffect part ?  @Viet

Comment: No. Full detail component.

Comment: If you added the console.log in a useEffect with empty dependency array, then it will be empty, because that will executed before the return of your async request.